# How to add material ui to gatsby site generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I try to set up the Gatsby kit and deep in react with this site generator and material ui framework. What did I mess? I've got the error

```
 Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined
    at RaisedButton.render
```

I installed material ui with npm

```
npm install material-ui
```

After add the to components to my post index.js and MyAwesomeReactComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const MaterialUiWrapper = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

export default MaterialUiWrapper


exports.data = {
  title: "Material UI ",
  date: "2017-12-09T12:40:32.169Z",
}
```

MyAwesomeReactComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const MyAwesomeReactComponent = () => (
  <RaisedButton label="Default" />
);

export default MyAwesomeReactComponent;
```

Comment: Could you give more detail about where do you implement this or maybe show your repo?

Comment: FWIW I followed the same steps, but I did it to my Gatsby layout components, and it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add this `default theme`, add this lines it will work:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
```

Then add this `MuiTheme`:

```
const MaterialUiWrapper = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
)
```

Comment: it is not necessarily as I remember. MuiThemeProvider will provide the default theme anyway

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but for anyone looking for an answer, [material-ui repo now has an example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/gatsby) . It uses an higher order component called "withRoot" to wrap each page.

There is also a [gatsby material-ui plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-material-ui) although it presently uses material-ui v1-beta (not the latest as at time of this answer)